# Using pointer functions in factory generates compile time error

Tags: c++, function

I have the following using declaration

```
template<typename T> using createShapeFunction = Shape<T>(*)(void);
```

This is for a factory so when I define the createShape() method I use the following syntax:

```
createShapeFunction<T>* function = creationFunctions.at(nameOfType);
Shape<T>* returnShape = *function();
```

Now this gives me the error:

```
error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments
```

Can anyone please tell me why?

**Edit:** I forgot to mention the following:

- creationFunction is of type std::map< std::string, createShapeFunction < T> *> creationFunctions
- the function that I use to create the objects have the following signature static Shape* __stdcall Create()

Comment: Which line does the message correspond to?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth to the Shape<T>* returnShape = *function();

Comment: @ciprianr That line tries to call `function` and then dereference the result. That's probably not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

From your using clause, `createShapeFunction<T>` is a pointer to a function which takes no arguments and returns a `Shape<T>`.

`createShapeFunction<T>* f` declares `f` as a pointer to a `createShapeFunction<T>`.  Hence, `f` is a pointer to a pointer to a function which takes no arguments and returns a `Shape<T>`

Try `createShapeFunction<T> function` instead, which should work.

---

From your edit, the problem I described above isn't your issue.  I find the use of a pointer to a pointer to a function to be highly suspect.  I'm curious how you inserted the functions into the map.

That said, if you REALLY want this, as pointed out by François Moisan, you need to use your original definition of `function` and use

`Shape<T> returnShape = (*function)();`

Note, return shape is a `Shape<T>`, since that's what the function returns.

Comment: tried that and got cannot convert from 'Shape<int> (__cdecl **)(void)' to 'Shape<int> (__cdecl *)(void)'

Comment: @ciprianr if function really must be a pointer to pointer to function, then you should be calling it as `(*function)()`. `*` here has higher priority. You are also trying to assign to a `Shape<T>*` while the function is declared as returing `Shape<T>`